# Tensorflow model with model property and 2 inputs fails to predict on dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have this situation where I want a tensorflow model (parent model) to have as a property another tensorflow model (child model).

In the forward pass, I want the parent model to perform the forward pass on the child model with a subset of the inputs and then do some other stuff with the rest of the inputs (for anyone curious, I want to do [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/io/issues/146#issuecomment-626036107)).

However, when using the parent model to predict on a tensorflow dataset (`model.predict(ds)`), it fails with

```
TypeError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1147 predict_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1122 predict_step  **
        return self(x, training=False)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:934 __call__
        str(e) + '\n"""')

    TypeError: You are attempting to use Python control flow in a layer that was not declared to be dynamic. Pass `dynamic=True` to the class constructor.
    Encountered error:
    """
    in user code:

        <ipython-input-6-faa2eaf00084>:10 call  *
            actual_inputs, filename = inputs
        /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:561 __iter__
            self._disallow_iteration()
        /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:554 _disallow_iteration
            self._disallow_when_autograph_enabled("iterating over `tf.Tensor`")
        /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:532 _disallow_when_autograph_enabled
            " decorating it directly with @tf.function.".format(task))

        OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did not convert this function. Try decorating it directly with @tf.function.

    """
```

This problem is not happening with the following code:

```py
inp = next(iter(ds))
model.predict(inp)
```

I don't understand why this happens.

You can find the minimal reproducible example [on colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14Rr_t6kY8EGb3f40sf1IH07USU-nmXv4?usp=sharing).

Comment: When adding colab link, make sure it's public.

Comment: ooops thanks, can you tell me if it's ok now?